# Why is it q.join() and not t.join()?

Tags: python, multithreading

This is a multi-threading program that i found online. Can some one please explain why it is `q.join()` and not `t.join()`?

```
from threading import Thread, Lock, current_thread
import threading
import Queue


def worker(q, lock):
    while True:
        value = q.get() 

        with lock:
            print("In {} got value {}".format(threading.current_thread(), value))
       q.task_done()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue.Queue()

    num_threads = 10
    lock = Lock()

    for i in range(num_threads):
        t = Thread(target=worker, args=(q, lock))
        t.daemon = True  # dies when the main thread dies
        t.start()

    for x in range(1, 21):
        q.put(x)

    q.join()

    print('main done')
```

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the `join` call is to wait until all the work is done, not to wait until the thread that's doing the work is destroyed. So it waits for the queue to be finished.

Comment: You can join daemon threads. The difference between daemon and non-daemon threads is that daemon threads will be abruptly terminated with no cleanup when all non-daemon threads have exited.

Comment: (Joining this *particular* daemon thread would hang, because it loops indefinitely, but daemon-ness doesn't prevent joining.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using Queue `q`, you are asking the program to `join` for the all the items that you've been adding to the queue `q` instead of asking each `t` to join *individually*, see below quotes from [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html?highlight=queue#asyncio.Queue.join):

> coroutine join()
>
> ***Block*** until all items in the queue have been ***received and processed***.
>
> The count of unfinished tasks goes up whenever an item is added to
> the queue. The count goes down whenever a consumer coroutine calls
> task_done() to indicate that the item was retrieved and all work on it
> is complete. ***When the count of unfinished tasks drops to zero, join()
> unblocks***.